# {File Upload} $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] loads folder and no image with extention

Tags: php, file, upload

I have an image uploader which works fine on localhost through WAMP but when I push it live it doesn't work. Instead of having a temporary name like:

```
[tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\php53BF.tmp
```

It will return this:

```
[tmp_name] => /tmp/phpxfvHuw
```

I've checked my php.ini file and:

1. File upload size is 128mb (Plenty high enough)
2. File upload is enabled
3. I have *enctype="multipart/form-data"* in my form.
4. In $_FILES the error level is set to 0 which means there's no error.

What else could cause such an issue?

Comment: Can you actually save this file on the server without any issues?

Comment: You give a lot of data in the question, but one thing you don't say is *what is actually wrong with the `/tmp/phpxfvHuw` output.*

Comment: I don't see any issue with that, you can just use the temp file as per your needs, it doesn't matter what its called

Comment: Your server is probably a Linux server. On such servers the temporary folder is /tmp/ and your files temporary name is phpxfvHuw. So it seems to me that nothing is wrong. Or else you should add additional information to your question

Comment: @ MarcB - The file-path is being taken dynamically so I don't understand how it matters? @ Kojiro - The output isn't returning a file and just a folder so my function (move_uploaded_file) won't work I'm assuming? Or am I assuming incorrectly?

Comment: @JackNicholsonn why don't you try to move uploaded file to check if it works?

Comment: @JackNicholsonn why do you think it's not a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check and make sure the folder you are uploading to has the proper permissions, you can do this with a simple chmod r 777 command. May I suggest permission on the upload folder be 775. This should give both the apache and FTP users the ability to write to the files in the folder but keep everyone else from modifying them.

You can always checked the (move_uploaded_files)'s ['error'] index for any errors that you may experience. If it is 0, then your upload was successful.

Check out this article if you need more information,
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp